# MS SQL Найти разницу между поступлениями и снятиями с банковского счета

Tags: sql, sql-server

Условно говоря есть таблица клиенты банка(clients) с 3 столбцами: Клиент(client), Тип операции(type), и Сумма(sum). Есть множество клиентов и есть множество операций пополнения и снятия с их счетов на различные суммы (type).

Как написать запрос, что бы получить состояние счета по каждому клиенту?

Я понимаю, как получить сумму всех снятий или поступлений по каждому клиенту. Но именно разницу между ними, никак не могу нормально прописать.

Задание отличается от описанного, но в этом суть.

Comment: `sum( case type when 1 then sum else -sum end )`

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить таким образом(самый простой на мой взгляд):

```sql
Declare @bank table(client_id int, op_type int, summ numeric(10,2))

insert into @bank
values (1, 1, 15), 
(1, 2, 15),
(1, 1, 5),
(1, 1, 7),
(1, 2, 1)

-- пусть 1 будет зачисление
-- 2 будет снятие с баланса
-- тогда делаем выборку из таблицы и группируем по клиенту

select client_id,  --берем Id клиента
sum(case op_type -- суммируем значения сумм и в зависимости от типа операции выбираем знак "сумм" 
                 when 1 then summ       --когда кладем значение положительное 
                 when 2 then -summ      --когда снимаем отрицательное
                 end) as [итого]
from @bank
group by client_id -- группируем по клиенту
```

данные в таблице и итоговый результат:
[image: результат]